# Automatically resize content when on mobile (bootstrap)

Tags: bootstrap-4

I inherited a bunch of HTML from a previous dev and I can see that bootstrap 4 is used, but the content was never optimized for mobile using divs like col-md-4 etc.

This may be a dumb question but I was wondering if there is a way to simply "zoom-in" the whole content while on mobile.

May be something can be specified in the main container div?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching more about "zooming in on mobile" found an answer here on SO

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

That did the trick